# how to retrieve thousands of rows from a stored procedure efficiently

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.0 + ADO.Net + SQL Server 2008. And from ADO.Net I am invoking a stored procedure from SQL Server side. The stored procedure is like this,

```
SELECT Table1.col2
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (col1)
WHERE Table2.col1 IS NULL
```

My question is, how to retrieve the returned rows (Table1.col2 in my sample) efficiently? My result may return up to 5,000 rows and the data type for Table1.col2 is nvarchar (4000).

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: You're using SQL Server 2008 with that syntax?

Comment: My pseudo code, what is the problem?

Comment: No problem, but it would confuse people because this is valid syntax for other database engines

Comment: Yes, I migrate from Oracle/DB2 some codes for SQL Server. :-)

Comment: Will you be paging the returned data?

Answer (score 7):

You **CANNOT** - you can NEVER retrieve that much data efficiently....

The whole point of being efficient is to limit the data you retrieve - only those columns that you really need (no SELECT *, but SELECT (list of fields), which you already do), and only as much rows as you can handle easily.

For instance, you don't want to fill a drop down or listbox where the user needs to pick a single value with thousands of entries - that's just not feasible.

So I guess my point really is: if you really, truly need to return 5000 rows or more, it'll just take its time. There's not much you can do about that (if you transmit 5000 rows with 5000 bytes per row, that's 25'000'000 bytes or 25 megabytes - no magic go make that go fast).

It'll only go really fast if you find a way to limit the number of rows returned to 10, 20, 50 or so. Think: server-side paging!! :-)

Marc

Comment: Thanks Marc, are there any performance differences how we manipulate the data from ADO.Net client side? I only need to sequentially read the returned data only once. What is the solution you suggest me to retrieve data from ADO.Net client side?

Comment: If you must retrieve those 5000 rows, the SqlDataReader is definitely the fastest and best way to go - grab the columns you need and store them in a List<T> or something.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what you want to do with the data. However, assuming you need to process the results in .NET then reading the results using an [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) would be the most efficient way.

Comment: I only need to sequentially read the returned data only once. What is the solution you suggest me to retrieve data from ADO.Net client side?

Comment: It depends on what your major concern is -memory or holding a connection to the database open for a long time. If you want to conserve memory then read one row at a time using the SqlDataReader,process it, and then move on to the next one. However, if memory is no big concern the do as suggested above and then use the SqlDataReader to create a List<T> where T is a class containing your columns. Read everything into the List<T> and then work with that afterward.

See http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19887/1954

Answer (score 2):

I'd use exists for one.

```
SELECT
    Table1.col2
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
         FROM
            Table2
         WHERE
            Table2.col1 = Table1.col1)
```

The query can be efficient (assume col1 is indexed but covers cols (very wide index of course), but you still have to shovel a lot of data over the network.

It depends what you mean by performance. 5000 rows isn't much for a report but it's a lot for a combo box